# How to add role by reacting in DM to a bot message

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to make a bot that send me a message with a reaction button, when I click it, give me a role in the server. Im trying to use on_raw_reaction_add event but I cant reach a solution to make it, Im always getting errors at getting guild roles and this stuff.

In this case, guild is none, I dont know what Im doing wrong.

My code:

```
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):  
    global member
    global message__id
    global channel_id
    
    channel_id = (ctx.channel.id)
    member = ctx.message.author
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Verify your account", color=0x03fc14)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Verification!", value=('React to this message to get verified!'), inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    mesg = await member.send(embed=embed)
    await mesg.add_reaction("✅")
    message__id = mesg.id
    print("EXECUTED")
    


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print("reacted")
    print("messageid accepted")
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)

    if guild is not None:
        print("messageid accepted")
        reactor = payload.guild.get_member(payload.member.id)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Member")

        if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
            print("emoji accepted")
            await reactor.add_roles(role)
```

**EDIT:**

I changed  my on_raw_reaction_add event:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    print("reacted")
    print("messageid accepted")
    guild = client.get_guild(payload.guild_id)

    if guild is not None:
        print("guild not none ")
        reactor = payload.guild.get_member(payload.member.id)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="Verified")

        if payload.emoji.name == '✅':
            print("emoji accepted")
            await reactor.add_roles(role)
    else:
        print("guild none")
```

And this is what happen when I try the method:

First three words are the prints of the bot reacting his own message, the "EXECUTED" is the print of test method and the last three messages. are when I react the bot message

[image]

Comment: Did you mean `guild is None`? In a DM, there is no guild.

Comment: Yes, pls, check my post again, I edited it and wrote more details about it

Comment: What happens if you change it to that?

Comment: It still going to else clause so it says guild is none for some reason

Comment: But why? If you want them to react in the DM, then you want the guild to be `None`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I suggest using a `wait_for` rather than `on_raw_reaction_add`.

Example, as seen in the docs:

```
@client.command(aliases=["t"])
async def test(ctx):  

    embed = discord.Embed(title="Verify your account", color=0x03fc14)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Verification!", value=('React to this message to get verified!'), inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    # sends message to command author
    mesg = await ctx.author.send(embed=embed)
    
    await mesg.add_reaction("✅")

    #check if the reactor is the user and if that reaction is the check mark
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'

    try:
        #wait for the user to react according to the checks
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        # 60 seconds without reaction
        await ctx.send('Timed out')
    else:
        await ctx.send('✅')
```

docs- https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for

Answer (score 0):

```
async def test(ctx):  
    global member
    global message__id
    global channel_id
    
    channel_id = (ctx.channel.id)
    member = ctx.message.author
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Verify your account", color=0x03fc14)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Verification!", value=('React to this message to get verified!'), inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    mesg = await member.send(embed=embed)
    await mesg.add_reaction("✅")
    message__id = mesg.id
    print("EXECUTED")
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role id here)
    done = False
    while done == False:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for(“reaction_add”, check=check)
        if user == client.user:
            continue
        await member.add_roles(role)
        done = True
```

I am pretty sure something like this would work :D

Answer (score 0):

When you do `guild is not None`, it will never fire because you are reacting in a DM channel context - where the guild *is* `None`. To access the guild information from the DM, you'll need to save it somewhere in the message (or save it yourself internally). Then, you have the guild object and you're able to add roles or do things to it.

```py
@client.command()
async def testrole(ctx):
    member = ctx.author
    # ...
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Verify your account", color=0x03fc14)
    embed.add_field(name=f"Verification!", value=('React to this message to get verified!'), inline=False)
    embed.set_footer(text=ctx.author, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    mesg = await member.send(str(ctx.guild.id), embed=embed)  # we need the guild information somewhere
    await mesg.add_reaction("✅")

@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):  # there's really no need to use raw event here
    if user.id == client.user.id:
        return
    if reaction.message.guild is None:
        if reaction.emoji == '\u2705':
            # we have to get the guild that we saved in the other function
            # there is no other way to know the guild, since we're reacting in the DM
            # that's why it was saved inside of the message that was sent to the user
            guild_id = int(reaction.message.content)
            guild = client.get_guild(guild_id)
            member = guild.get_member(user.id)
            await member.add_roles(...)  # change this with your roles
```